# extjs 4.1.0 controller's init function won't be called

Tags: javascript, extjs, javascript-framework, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I'm fairly new to both javascript and extjs and I encountered this problem while trying to run through the steps of the extjs 4.1 MVC Architecture tutorial. Evereything works fin in the beginning but when I try to add the controller to the application something goes wrong. Neither the applications launch function nor the controllers init function is called. I used the sample code from here [here](http://afsweb.ms.com/ms/dev/ria/ext/4.1.0/src/ext-4.1.0-gpl/docs/index.html#!/guide/application_architecture)  but I couldn't get the 'defining a controller' step working. It finds the Users.js there's no error message, still it won't call the controllers init function. If I remove the 'controllers: ['Users'],' the applications launch will be called. Any ideas what I'm missing?

app.js:

```
Ext.application({
requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
name: 'Account Manager',

appFolder: 'app',

controllers: ['Users'],

launch: function() {...}
```

Users.js:

```
Ext.define('app.controller.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

init: function() {
        console.log('Initialized Users!');
}
});
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hmmm... I take it you just missed `});` at the end of `app.js`? Also do you get any errors on your console?

Comment: The syntax is correct it's just i didn't copy it precisely. And no I don't get any error messages on the console unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is (Ext.Application)

```
name: 'Account Manager',
```

Here's the API link for the **[name property](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-name)**.

Change it to:

```
name: 'app', // I would use camelcase here
```

***Explanation:***

You are not allowed to use spaces in the application name. Further it is more a namespace then a name. You have to use it in all of your classes (This will be the namespace for your views, controllers models and stores) afterwards.

Comment: It did make it work, thank you. I thought it's the appfolder parameter that counts here but it was the name.